# Less conditional expectation error for bigger $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X\in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{G}_1\subset \mathcal{G}_2 \subset \mathcal{F}$. Show that

$$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_2])^2]\leq \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1])^2]$$
$\newcommand {\E}  {\mathbb{E}}$
Interpret this result by considering $\mathcal{G}_1$ and $\mathcal{G}_2$ to be levels of knowledge. [Hint: Add and subtract $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_2]$ in an appropriate manner]

$\textbf{My attempt}$

$$\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1])^2]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1]+\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_2]-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_2])^2]=L$$

Let us expand the expression above
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        L=&\mathbb{E}[X^2+\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1]^2+\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]^2+\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]^2-2X\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1]-2X\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]+2X\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2] \\
        &+2\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1]-2\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1]\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]-2\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]^2]
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

After rearranging and combining terms together
    $$L=\E[(X-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2])^2+(\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1]-E[X|\mathcal{G}_2])^2+2(\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1])(X-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2])]$$

Clearly, $\E[(\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1]-E[X|\mathcal{G}_2])^2]\geq 0$.

I don't know what to do with the term $\color{red}{\E[2(\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1])(X-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2])]}$, in other words, I don't really know how to argue that that term will be non-negative. I suspect here I need to use the fact that $\mathcal{G}_1\subset \mathcal{G}_2\subset \mathcal{F}$. Something is that for $G\in \mathcal{G}_1$, that term becomes $0$, because $(\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2]-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_1])=0$. For $G\in \mathcal{G}_2$, that term becomes $0$, because $(X-\E[X|\mathcal{G}_2])=0$. However, for $G\in \mathcal{F}$, I don't know what happens.

It is entirely possible I have a terrible misconception or I am missing something obvious, but in any case, I'd appreciate any hint or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in red is in fact equal to zero:

Writing $X_i=\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}_i]$ ($i=1,2$) for the sake of brevity, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[(X_2-X_1)(X-X_2)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(X_2-X_1)(X-X_2)\mid\mathcal{G}_2]]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[(X_2-X_1)\mathbb{E}[X-X_2\mid \mathcal{G}_2]]$$
since $X_2-X_1$ is $\mathcal{G}_2$-measurable (because $\mathcal{G}_1\subset \mathcal{G}_2$), and then
$$ \mathbb{E}[X-X_2\mid \mathcal{G}_2]=X_2-X_2=0 $$
and so the whole expectation is zero.

Comment: Why do you have $\mathbb{E}[(X_2-X_1)(X-X_2)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(X_2-X_1)(X-X_2)\mid\mathcal{G}_2]]$? I ask because $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable but not $\mathcal{G}_2$-measurable.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z\mid \mathcal{G}_1]]=\mathbb{E}[Z]$ for any (integrable) random variable $\mathcal{G}_1$, this is sometimes called the law of total expectation.

Comment: The answer is clear, but I have a question. I started with $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1])^2]$. What happens if I start with $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_2]$, and add $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1]$ the same way I did it. The result will be the same up to the red expression. $X_1-X_2$ is not $\mathcal{G}_1$-measurable, but $\mathbb{E}[X-X_1|\mathcal{G}_1]=0$, so wouldn't the whole expression become $0$? thus leading to a contradiction. In simpler words, why does not work to add and subtract $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}_1]$?

Comment: Since $X_1-X_2$ isn't $\mathcal{G}_1$-measurable, you wouldn't be able to pull it out of a conditional expectation given $\mathcal{G}_1$ and so the argument in my answer wouldn't work.